# Не могу подключиться к БД MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

Добрый день
Буквально вчера всё работало. Сегодня же, после включения, пишет вот такое[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу это исправить?
Спасибо

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше проводить в виде текста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Зайдите Windows служба сервиса **(CMD -> services.msc)**.
2. Лево находится кнопка запустите(Start) **SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER) / SQL Server Browser**.

Проверьте сервисы (который отмеченные в картине) -
[дополнительный руководство](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/start-stop-pause-resume-restart-sql-server-services).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]